# What is Nemesis 2.0?

Tags: identify-this-game

I'm interested in buying [Nemesis](http://awakenrealms.com/games/nemesis/) but in my country's only place that sells it it is listed as a pre-order for Nemesis 2.0 (2020).

Link (in Bulgarian): https://boardgames-bg.com/nemesis-2.0-2020-board-game.html

Does anyone have any idea if there IS such a thing as "Nemesis 2.0" as I didn't find anything about it on The 'Net?

Comment: This is not a proper example of [semantic versioning](https://semver.org). Very confusing! Thank you for asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just the next printing of the game.

See https://www.rebelgames.eu/games/nemesis-1003.html

> Next print of Nemesis is expected q3 2020.